# Passing multiple scope (ACL) middlewares to routes are only testing for the first scope

Tags: node.js, express, acl

My application is supposed to have 3 user scopes (User, Admin, Super Admin). I am trying to do this manually without using any external ACL library.

Here are my admin and super admin scope functions.

```
const adminScope = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user.scope !== 'admin') {
        return res.status(403).send({
            status: 'fail',
            message: 'You are not admin'
        })
    }
    next();
}


const superAdminScope = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user.scope !== 'superAdmin') {
        return res.status(403).send({
            status: 'fail',
            message: 'You are not Super Admin'
        })
    }
    next();
}
```

I am trying to use these with my routes as below

```
app.use('/admin', [passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), adminScope], [adminPage])
```

The above works fine and checks if the scope of the user is `admin` or not.

I want all the routes in `adminPages` to be accessible by both Admins and Super Admins.

I tried by passing `superAdminScope` as third middleware.

```
app.use('/admin', [passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), adminScope, superAdminScope], [adminPage])
```

It fails after checking just `adminScope` function and says

```
{
  status: "fail",
  message: "You are not admin"
}
```

I also tried passing both of them as an array but still the same output.

```
app.use('/admin', [passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), [adminScope, superAdminScope]], [adminPage])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using [this](https://developerhandbook.com/passport.js/passport-role-based-authorisation-authentication/) tutorial.

Instead of having separate functions for `admin` and `superAdmin`, I created a function to check for It.

```
const checkForScope = (...scopes) => (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.user) {
        return res.status(403).send({
            status: 'fail',
            message: 'You are not logged in'
        })
    }

    const hasScope = scopes.find(scope => req.user.scope === scope)

    if (!hasScope) {
        return res.status(403).send({
            status: 'fail',
            message: 'You dont have the rights to do this'
        })
    }

    return next();
}
```

And then I can use this function as middleware in express.

```
app.use('/admin', [passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), checkForScope('admin', 'superAdmin')], [adminPage])
```

This will only allow users access to the routes if they have either `admin` or `superAdmin` scope.

I'm not sure If this is the best way to do this but It's working.